# Rails will_paginate routing caching duplicate pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, will-paginate

I use the will_paginate plug-in.

In oder to generate routes that I can cache ( `/posts/index/2` instead of `/posts?page=2`) I added the following to my routes.rb:

```
map.connect '/posts/index/1', :controller => 'redirect', :url => '/posts/'  

map.connect 'posts/index/:page',
          :controller => 'posts',
          :action => 'index',
          :requirements => {:page => /\d+/ },
          :page => nil
```

The first line redirects `/posts/index/1` to `/posts/` using a redirect controller, to avoid having a duplicate page.

Is there something wrong with the way I set up the `'posts/index/:page'` rule?

I thought adding `:requirements => {:page => /\d+/ }` would ensure that `/post/index/` without a `:page` parameter should not work, but  `/posts/index.html` is getting cached.

How can I redirect `/posts/index/` to `/posts/` to avoid having both `/posts.html` and `/posts/index.html` ?

Thanks

---

UPDATE

I simply added

```
map.connect '/posts/index/', :controller => 'redirect', :url => '/posts/'
```

And I'm not getting duplicate pages anymore.

However, I still don't uderstand why I was getting `/posts/index.html`. Any explanations or suggestions on how to make this rule more succinct are welcome ;)!

```
map.connect '/posts/index/1', :controller => 'redirect', :url => '/posts/'  
map.connect '/posts/index/', :controller => 'redirect', :url => '/posts/'
map.connect 'posts/index/:page',
          :controller => 'posts',
          :action => 'index',
          :requirements => {:page => /\d+/ },
          :page => nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-requirements) I found possible answer to your question.

I think that adding `:page => nil` can override previous condition. So maybe when you remove this part, it will work as you expected.

Comment: Thank you, I will certainly try that and come back to update this thread.